# How to avoid edge collisions in tile-based physics (Unity2D Physics)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics-engine

I'm working on a **2D** side-scrolling **physics-based game**.

The maps for this game are created following a **tile-based system** that reads from a text file, and blocks are created on the game to draw the level. Some objects, using physics' gravity, need to **"slide" across sections of multiple blocks placed together** (like floors, but built from different blocks, due to the tile-based system).

Even though blocks are placed "mathematically" exactly one by the other, because **each block has its own BoxCollider2D, the physics engine still detects the "edge" sometimes**, and the object that should be sliding across the multiple block section (which also has a BoxCollider2D, plus a RigidBody2D) just crazily bounces off off the surface (I'm assuming because of edge / edge collision).

I've tried adding a small edge radius, but it doesn't really work. Is there any way in which I could easily **"link" those block sections together**, or to **"smooth" the edges** in such a way that the physics engine wouldn't realise they are there?

I'm attaching 4 images to make everything more understandable and clear:

1. Floor block BoxCollider2D inspector properties.
2. Moving object BoxCollider2D and RigidBody2D properties.
3. Game screenshot (moving object standing on a "floor" formed by various independent blocks; note that the sprite is rounded, by the BoxCollider2D attached to the object is not).
4. Game screenshot on editor, with various blocks highlighted to show how their BoxCollider2D boxes (supposedly) overlap, which shouldn't leave any edge for the moving object to collide with.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Floor block BoxCollider2D inspector properties]
[image: Moving object BoxCollider2D and RigidBody2D properties.]
[image: Game screenshot (moving object standing on a "floor" formed by various independent blocks; note that the sprite is rounded, by the BoxCollider2D attached to the object is not).]
[image: Game screenshot on editor, with various blocks highlighted to show how their BoxCollider2D boxes (supposedly) overlap, which shouldn't leave any edge for the moving object to collide with.]

Comment: I feel you, as I recently encountered the same ghost seams phenomenon [in 3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59792261/simplify-collision-mesh-of-road-like-system). A suggestion, if no one suggests anything better: Remove the box colliders from your tile prefabs. Then during Start(), analyze the block structure and add custom (invisible, no mesh renderer) gameObjects with BoxColliders that span the respective multiple rows or columns. This gets rid of the bumping. (It's not terrific in all cases, though, e.g. what if you had a bridge tile which only lifts on press.)

Comment: Thanks Philipp, I've starting implementing that and seems it's going on the right direction! :)