# How to make Quads flush with each other

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a game where I move a red cube across a plane with arrow keys (I am setting the velocity in order to get a constant speed) Here is a preview:

[game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXOoq.png)

Currently, I am just using a plane with a grid material/texture. However, I wanted to change one of the tiles in this grid to a different color and detect when my cube passes over it.

My idea was to simply replace the plane with a bunch of quads. However, when I do that and try to navigate my cube across the quads, it seems to collide with the side of the quad and flip up, despite the fact that they are all at the same height and positioned right next to each other.

Is there a way to make the quads flush so when I push my cube over it, it won't collide with the side of the quads? Is there a better way to create this behavior?

Comment: For what it's worth, I've had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59792261/simplify-collision-mesh-of-road-like-system), and am still looking for a proper fix. Rigidbodies in Unity seem to have big problems with these "ghost seams" even when, as you say, the quads are perfectly aligned (making them slightly bigger doesn't help either). If you switch to a CharacterController, it may be able to absorb the bumps, though.

Comment: I don't think I want to use a CharacterController because I still want physics involved. I also looked at your linked question and tried to use CombineMeshes on the quads but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Right. In that case, you could change the collision of the different-color quad to be a trigger (the "is trigger" checkbox in the inspector pane), but keep the plane below all. Triggers won't affect physics, yet they can register collisons von `OnEnterTrigger`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable colliders at this quads and add invisible big plane with collider

Comment: This worked perfectly. I added an invisible plane with quads on the same level. However, in order to detect collisions with a specific quad but prevent movement, I kept the collider and just made it a trigger